# Carter's construction of the Chevalley group (Case $A_1$)

Tags: lie-algebras, simple-groups, root-systems

I am currently working through Carter's book ["Simple Groups of Lie Type"](https://books.google.de/books?id=nW9tPZUMkdIC&lpg=PR1&hl=de&pg=PA64#v=onepage&q&f=false), trying to explicitly construct the generators of the Chevalley group of the root system $A_1$.

In the context of $A_1$ let $\Phi = \{ a, -a \}$ be the root system and $\Pi = \{ a \}$ the single simple root.

In §4.4 (page 64 in the link above) Carter gives explicit formulas for how the automorphism $x_r(t)$ for $r \in \Phi$ operates on elements of the Chevally basis, in my case $\{h_a\} \cup \{e_a, e_{-a} \}$.

**Question 1:** I am confused how $x_r(t)$ operates on $e_{-r}$. Carter writes that for all $r \in \Phi$ (!) we have
$$x_r(t).e_{-r} = e_{-r} + th_r - t^2 e_{r}$$
This makes sense for $r = a$ but if I consider $r = -a$ and $x_{-a}(t).e_a$ then this leads to a term including $h_{-a}$ (in the formula above) which is not part of the Chevalley basis.

**Question 2:** Is it really necessary to take $x_r(t)$ for all $r \in \Phi$ to have a generating set of the Chevalley group? Or can a stronger statement be made (i.e. only take $\pm \Pi$ or something?)? I could not find anything in the book so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's "Chevalley", I edited to fix. Pronounced more "-lay" (or even more like in "lettuce": no diphtongue), and not like "key".

Comment: I assume there is a convention that $h_{-\alpha}$ is either $h_\alpha$ or $-h_\alpha$. Would one of these consistently solve the problem in question 1?

Comment: YCor: Thanks! I'll remember that.  
@TorstenSchoeneberg Mh, not really. In $A_2$ there are two simple roots $\alpha, \beta$, thus $h_\alpha$ and $h_\beta$ as basis elements of the Cartan subalgebra. Furthermore, $\alpha + \beta \in \Phi$. Thus there would be an expression $x_{\alpha + \beta}(t).e_{-\alpha - \beta}$ leading to $h_{\alpha + \beta}$ (not part of the basis) which cannot be resolved by just switching the sign. Perhaps Carter assumes linearity as in $h_{\alpha - \beta} = h_\alpha - h_\beta$ but I can't find a reference for that.

Comment: In the book link you provided, I cannot go back to where he first defines Chevalley bases; however, up to sign switches there must be some relations like $[e_\alpha, e_{-\alpha}] = h_\alpha$ and $[e_\alpha, e_\beta] = \pm N_{\alpha, \beta} \cdot e_{\alpha+\beta}$. To have all this consistently extended from roots in $\Pi$ to the entire root system will force $h_{-\alpha} =-h_{\alpha}$ by anticommutativity, and express/define $h_{\alpha+\beta}$ as linear combination of $h_{\alpha}, h_{\beta}$ by the Jacobi identity.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks for the advice, that makes sense. I should really and now will look into these relations that produce the formulas I use.